# Composer error when I want to install fosuserbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I use this command in cmd

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

I get this message

> Please provide a version constraint for the
>   friendsofsymfony/user-bundle requirement: 2.0.*@dev composer.json has
>   been updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
>   not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>       - A typo in the package name
>       - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion
>   for more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting composer.json to its original content.

I've already added "minimum-stability": "dev", in my composer.json

It's the first time that I head this problem I installed fosuserbundle manytimes and it worked before.

Comment: could you post your composer.json

Comment: why are you trying to check out a dev version?  wouldn't an official release version be better?

Comment: @parakash i add my composer.json please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed, it should be:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

not

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ": "~2.0@dev"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just Advice you just use this to configure all the sonata admin + fos user bundle without any dependencies or version conflicts

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.x-dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3@dev",       
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1@dev",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.x-dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "dev-master",        
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev"
},
```